# How to make Android layout proportional regardless of screen size and orientation

Tags: android, android-layout, orientation, screen-size

This is my first post here. I just learned Android programming and come to this problem. I have searched a bit and found some solutions but I couldn't make my code works. So I want to know which part of my code or implementation is wrong.

So, the problem is I want to make a layout which will stays the same proportion on different screen sizes and orientation. Here are my code:

*activity_main.xml*

```html
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp" >
        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:id="@+id/textView4"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/textView5"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:id="@+id/textView6"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:max="255"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I can't post screenshot at the moment, because it said "You need at least 10 reputation to post images."

So, I want to divide the screen by 3 parts vertically, and divide the top part by 2 horizontally and the bottom part by 3 horizontally and maintain their proportion regardless of screen size, resolution, and orientation.

The only part that didn't work is the top block, on the code I set it to `android:layout_height="150dp"` because the layout somehow is broken if I set those to `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`. But this doesn't make the layout to be proportional if I change the orientation. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You should read about `LinearLayout` & `weight`!

Comment: if you want 150dp layout than why are you using weight concept for other layout?

Comment: Hi, thank you very much about the hint. I found the problem now. I was setting those to `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` but forgot to set the `weight`. Sorry, a beginner's mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `layout_weight` on the three `linearLayout` and assigning to each one the same value, the screen will bi divided vertically to 3 regardless of the screen size. Also, assign the height to `0dp`: `android:layout_height="0dp"`

The complete xml would be:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="255" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems people have already answered your question while I was making this.
[image]
Nonetheless, I'm posting this answer in case you still need help. This image contains the weights you need to assign to your layouts, expressed graphically. Please excuse some lack of alignment, I made this in a rush.

Answer (score 4):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#555555">

   <LinearLayout 
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:background="#555555">
       <TextView 
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:text="part1"
           android:background="#008000"/>
       <TextView 
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:text="part2"
           android:background="#0000FF"/>
   </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout 
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:background="#ffffff"></LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout 
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:background="#000000">
       <TextView 
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:text="part1"
           android:background="#008000"/>
       <TextView 
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:text="part2"
           android:background="#A9F114"/>
       <TextView 
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:text="part3"
           android:background="#B4155D"/>
   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may also get the screen dimension pragmatically and set the height/weight based on your requirement.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics ();
    display.getMetrics(outMetrics);

    float density  = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    float dpHeight = outMetrics.heightPixels / density;
    float dpWidth  = outMetrics.widthPixels / density;
```